# My animated favicon does not show animation

Tags: html, favicon

I am using these

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I can see favicon in my address bar but no animation? What else am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get rid of the first line pointing to the `favicon.png` so that you have only

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

And ensure that the `favicon.ico` is a **real** animated favicon and not something renamed. You can use http://www.animatedfavicon.com or http://www.favicongenerator.org to convert an animated `.gif` file to an animated `.ico` file.

Comment: I can't get this to work in Chrome - Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe some browsers simply do not support animated favicons.  So you may want to check around on different browsers and realize that on some you may have a static icon, while on others it looks just as you wanted it to.

Comment: Also, some browsers may have cached an old non-animated favicon.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers don't support them like Chrome or Safari but it works quite well in Firefox....Keeping in mind that you use a .ico file.