# Making a video to play as my websites favicon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

[This](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/) plugin can make a video to play as your site's favicon by using this code:

```
var favicon=new Favico();
var video=document.getElementById('videoId');
favicon.video(video);
//stop
favicon.video('stop');
```

here's the [Github](https://github.com/ejci/favico.js) page.

I tried to make the video play automatically without any input but
unfortunately I couldn't get it to work with my site.

P.s:  I'm just a beginner so if anybody have any suggestions or maybe a **fiddle** to work it out that'll be great!

Comment: I suggest you post your complete code: html+js. So we can better help you. Do you actually have a video file in your document, with id : 'videoId' ?

Comment: can you make it a gif? that should be easier than a video

Comment: @darthrubens here: http://pastebin.com/Rz37QxCr

Comment: @JordanHendrix If you can do it please give it a try  :)

Comment: I watched the source of the website you posted, they dont play a video, they rapidly change the src of the favicon to different images. You can see this by inspecting element favicon

Comment: @Zack Ok, that's a lot of code :) Let me try to make a simple example

Comment: If someone finds the answer, I'd like to see it as well, I tried to make it work, without success: http://rubentd.com/demos/favicon/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `<video>` to your html

here's a sample code

```
<video id="videoId" width="300">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    Video tag not supported. Download the video <a href="video.mp4">here</a>.
</video>
```

EDIT

The secret to getting this working is having the video on the same domain and not loading it from other domain.

Also, you need to add a `shortcut icon` in the title beforehand
so in your title you need to add this

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png">`

having it in png is the key Here's an example. Have a look https://j99.in/favicon

Comment: could you give me a fiddle with everything in its place?

Comment: Why wouldn't you try?

Comment: Can you remove `favicon.video('stop');` this and try? It wont work on jsfiddle because it loads results in an iframe

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to replace the video with an animated gif?

Comment: Bro! animated gifs are so much more easy. If you wanted animated gif why did you go the hard way? check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982282/my-animated-favicon-does-not-show-animation

Comment: I already tried it, It doesn't work in chrome! which browser are you using?

Comment: I have answered your original question. :) Why don't you post another question so that the community can get working on that

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using the video.play() feature? See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp

Since I don't have your video to test out, perhaps you could try this?

```
favicon.video(video.play());
```

Or adding the "autoplay" keyword to the video tag. See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

```
<video id="videoId" controls autoplay>...</video>
```

Then add an `onended` event for the video, so that it stops after the video finishes playing. Otherwise, it may try to stop right after the `favicon.video(video);` function, thus giving the illusion that it's not starting to play at all. It's probably starting & then a few milliseconds later, stopping.

```
video.onended = function() {
    favicon.video('stop');
};
```

(Mobile Note: From experience with building video players, I've discovered that auto-play won't work on all mobile devices. [Apple](http://www.apple.com) blocks it due to prevent websites from automatically consuming a user's monthly alloted bandwidth. So mobile users have to press the video play button, to start videos on iPhones & iPads.)

Comment: You need to add an id to your `<video>` tag specifically `videoId`

Comment: @Rohit I've added `id="videoId"`, so that it will work with Zack's code. The autoplay is really what my `<video>` tag example was showcasing. However, the id is a fine addition. I use them all the time in my code, but not always in SO demos. Thank you for the helpful reminder! :)

Comment: So was yours. So I did the same. :)

Answer (score -1):

This may be helpful to you

**HTML  autoplay Attribute**

```
<video controls autoplay>
```

sample script

```
<script> 
  var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

  function playVid() { 
     vid.play(); 
  } 

  function pauseVid() { 
    vid.pause(); 
  } 
</script>
```

sample html:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
 <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

For reference:[click me](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp)

Comment: This is not what the OP wants

Comment: Okay I just suggested no issues